# Build a app.exe file. Where to release it?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release-management

I have a specific question about Azure DevOps Pipeline CI/CD. I'm use to create CI and CD pipeline for IIS web application deployments. Sometime, I also do Click Once deployments.

This time, I'm using Azure DevOps Pipeline for creating and saving a very simple app.exe. This is a console application I want to make available as a downloadable tool for my company. I plan to create more small similar small app in future. with .NET Core I can easily integrate all my dependencies in the executable package and create a unique exe that can be used by some people from my company.

My question is how can I make this app.exe accessible as a downloadable file. Do I need to create my own FTP system to upload the app.exe and create a web page to give the minimum of information to my users? Or, can I use something from Azure directly? Can I deploy all my app.exe versions as a feed in the Artifact section?

It seems on some Git website like Github or Sourceforge there is a tab that keep all files. I'm looking for something similar on Azure DevOps

example:
https://github.com/Argent77/NearInfinity/releases
https://github.com/zarunbal/LogExpert/releases

Answer (score 3):

A good approach for distributing .Net Core console applications is to make them a [dotnet tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create) and publish them to a Nuget feed. It should be as simple as adding some config to the csproj and run `dotnet pack` This assumes you have a private Nuget feed for your company which Azure DevOps can provide if you don't.